# Laravel 5.3 - TokenMismatch, using post method, I don't have a form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I found a plethora of links telling me to insert csrf on the form. But what to do when you **don't** have a form? I use the post method to allow for other apps to post stuff on the database.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $solicitation = new Solicitation;
        $solicitation->name = $request->name;
        $solicitation->description = $request->description;
        $solicitation->userid = $request->userid;
        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
            $request->file('file')->move("uploads", $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName());
            $solicitation->file = "http://192.168.1.85:3232/uploads/" . $request->file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
        }
        $solicitation->save();
    }
}
```

And the error:

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 68:
```

**edit**

## Workaround / Solution

**Step 1)** Edit the file: VerifyCsrfToken.php (app\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php)

**Step 2)** Modify the following:

```
protected $except = [
    'solicitation/*', //INSERT THE NAME OF YOUR ROUTE HERE
];
```

Enjoy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can edit the VerifyCsrfToken class in Http\Middleware to exclude routes

Comment: That is the actual way to do it, sorry I just assumed after finding the file the rest would be pretty much self explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `_token` parameter to be sent with request every time you use `POST` method.

Comment: What do I add on the token parameter?

Comment: Can you update your question and add your code creating request?

Comment: It's a bad idea to exclude CSRF token from request though

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options: excluding this route from csrf or sending the token with the request. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're describing an API. 
If you're sending the request from a separate Laravel application the tokens won't be congruent. 
The solution would be to generate a request signature/token on the external application that your current application is expecting and can verify. You can use Laravel Passport: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport